# Change fold level based on syntax in vim

Tags: c++, vim, fold

Given the following C++ code:

```
//
// Some comments at the begin of the code.
// For instance, license, author name, date.
// Referred as "Comment A"
//

namespace one {
  namespace two {

    // Here you have some code.
    // And this comment explain what the code is doing.
    void exampleFunction();

  }
}
```

and the following settings in my .vimrc

```
set foldmethod=syntax
autocmd Syntax c,cpp syntax region cCommentLicense start="^\s*//" end="\n\s*\(\S[^/]\|\_$\)"me=s,re=s,he=s fold
```

These settings enable me to fold paragraph where lines start with `//`.

### My question

When `foldlevel` is modified (using `zr` and `zm`), the first comment (Comment A) is automatically folded.
Is it possible to change its fold level (set it to 9 for instance) ?

The fold level of the other comments do not matter for me.

Answer (score 2):

With syntax-based folding, the fold level is determined by the syntax structure. To get a level-9 fold, you would have to define 9 nested syntax regions.

With `:set foldmethod=expr`, you have finer control over the fold levels, and can explicitly return `9`. As long as you're *only* folding comments, you can probably write a simple equivalent expression, but if there are other folded constructs, too, that will become complex fast.

Comment: Would you know a simple way of mixing fold method `expr` and `syntax`, like a `foldexpr` that would compute folds using syntax method and just change the level ?

Comment: @billx: The evaluation result of syntax folding is not directly accessible, and you cannot evaluate it without setting `'foldmethod'` to it. So you would have to toggle between the two, and that wouldn't perform too well.